# How to make a function occur more than once at click

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm using library to create a spin wheel [This is link to it](http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/examples/basic_code_wheel) 
What I want to do is add option for the player to spin NO. times and get NO. of prizes at once. so its one click and he gets NO. of prizes and there the normal option of one spin 1 prize which is already available in the game

So, I thought of repeating the function that spins the wheel multiple time and display multiple prizes But I didn't know how to do it. If anyone have an idea of how I can do this.

something like this

The `function` that should be repeated is `startspin()`
and on click on button NO. spin it should generate NO. prizes

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Canvas Winning Wheel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
           
            <br />
            
            <br />
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="power_controls">
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <table class="power" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <th align="center">Power</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="78" align="center" id="pw3" onClick="powerSelected(3);">High</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" id="pw2" onClick="powerSelected(2);">Med</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" id="pw1" onClick="powerSelected(1);">Low</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br />
                            <img id="spin_button" src="spin_off.png" alt="Spin" onClick="startSpin();" />
                            <br /><br />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="resetWheel(); return false;">Play Again</a><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(reset)
                            <br>
                            
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="438" height="582" class="the_wheel" align="center" valign="center">
                        <canvas id="canvas" width="434" height="434">
                            <p style="{color: white}" align="center">Sorry, your browser doesn't support canvas. Please try another.</p>
                        </canvas>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            // Create new wheel object specifying the parameters at creation time.
            let theWheel = new Winwheel({
                'numSegments'  : 8,     // Specify number of segments.
                'outerRadius'  : 212,   // Set outer radius so wheel fits inside the background.
                'textFontSize' : 28,    // Set font size as desired.
                'segments'     :        // Define segments including colour and text.
                [
                   {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 1'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 2'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 3'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 4'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 5'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 6'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 7'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 8'}
                ],
                'animation' :           // Specify the animation to use.
                {
                    'type'     : 'spinToStop',
                    'duration' : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
                    'spins'    : 8,     // Number of complete spins.
                    'callbackFinished' : alertPrize
                }
            });

            // Vars used by the code in this page to do power controls.
            let wheelPower    = 0;
            let wheelSpinning = false;

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Function to handle the onClick on the power buttons.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function powerSelected(powerLevel)
            {
                // Ensure that power can't be changed while wheel is spinning.
                if (wheelSpinning == false) {
                    // Reset all to grey incase this is not the first time the user has selected the power.
                    document.getElementById('pw1').className = "";
                    document.getElementById('pw2').className = "";
                    document.getElementById('pw3').className = "";

                    // Now light up all cells below-and-including the one selected by changing the class.
                    if (powerLevel >= 1) {
                        document.getElementById('pw1').className = "pw1";
                    }

                    if (powerLevel >= 2) {
                        document.getElementById('pw2').className = "pw2";
                    }

                    if (powerLevel >= 3) {
                        document.getElementById('pw3').className = "pw3";
                    }

                    // Set wheelPower var used when spin button is clicked.
                    wheelPower = powerLevel;

                    // Light up the spin button by changing it's source image and adding a clickable class to it.
                    document.getElementById('spin_button').src = "spin_on.png";
                    document.getElementById('spin_button').className = "clickable";
                }
            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Click handler for spin button.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function startSpin()
            {
                // Ensure that spinning can't be clicked again while already running.
                if (wheelSpinning == false) {
                    // Based on the power level selected adjust the number of spins for the wheel, the more times is has
                    // to rotate with the duration of the animation the quicker the wheel spins.
                    if (wheelPower == 1) {
                        theWheel.animation.spins = 3;
                    } else if (wheelPower == 2) {
                        theWheel.animation.spins = 8;
                    } else if (wheelPower == 3) {
                        theWheel.animation.spins = 15;
                    }

                    // Disable the spin button so can't click again while wheel is spinning.
                    document.getElementById('spin_button').src       = "spin_off.png";
                    document.getElementById('spin_button').className = "";

                    // Begin the spin animation by calling startAnimation on the wheel object.
                    theWheel.startAnimation();

                    // Set to true so that power can't be changed and spin button re-enabled during
                    // the current animation. The user will have to reset before spinning again.
                    wheelSpinning = true;
                }
            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Function for reset button.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function resetWheel()
            {
                theWheel.stopAnimation(false);  // Stop the animation, false as param so does not call callback function.
                theWheel.rotationAngle = 0;     // Re-set the wheel angle to 0 degrees.
                theWheel.draw();                // Call draw to render changes to the wheel.

                document.getElementById('pw1').className = "";  // Remove all colours from the power level indicators.
                document.getElementById('pw2').className = "";
                document.getElementById('pw3').className = "";

                wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Called when the spin animation has finished by the callback feature of the wheel because I specified callback in the parameters
            // note the indicated segment is passed in as a parmeter as 99% of the time you will want to know this to inform the user of their prize.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function alertPrize(indicatedSegment)
            {
                // Do basic alert of the segment text. You would probably want to do something more interesting with this information.
                alert("You have won " + indicatedSegment.text);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update to code **

```js
            // Create new wheel object specifying the parameters at creation time.
            var number_of_spin=0;
            let theWheel = new Winwheel({
                'numSegments'  : 8,     // Specify number of segments.
                'outerRadius'  : 212,   // Set outer radius so wheel fits inside the background.
                'textFontSize' : 28,    // Set font size as desired.
                'segments'     :        // Define segments including colour and text.
                [
                   {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 1'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 2'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 3'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 4'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 5'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 6'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 7'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 8'}
                ],
                'animation' :           // Specify the animation to use.
                {
                    'type'     : 'spinToStop',
                    'duration' : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
                    'spins'    : 8,     // Number of complete spins.
                    'callbackFinished' : alertPrize
                }
            });

            // Vars used by the code in this page to do power controls.
            let wheelPower    = 0;
            let wheelSpinning = false;

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Function to handle the onClick on the power buttons.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
           

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Click handler for spin button.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
             function startSpin()
            {
                
                // Ensure that spinning can't be clicked again while already running.
                if (wheelSpinning == false) {
                    // Based on the power level selected adjust the number of spins for the wheel, the more times is has
                    // to rotate with the duration of the animation the quicker the wheel spins.
                  

                    // Begin the spin animation by calling startAnimation on the wheel object.
                    theWheel.startAnimation();

                    // Set to true so that power can't be changed and spin button re-enabled during
                    // the current animation. The user will have to reset before spinning again.
                    wheelSpinning = true;
                }
            }
            function startSpin2()
            {
                
                
                // Ensure that spinning can't be clicked again while already running.
                if (wheelSpinning == false) {
                    // Based on the power level selected adjust the number of spins for the wheel, the more times is has
                    // to rotate with the duration of the animation the quicker the wheel spins.
                   number_of_spin++;
if(number_of_spin>0){
                    theWheel.animation.duration=0;
    theWheel.startAnimation();

                    // Set to true so that power can't be changed and spin button re-enabled during
                    // the current animation. The user will have to reset before spinning again.
                    wheelSpinning = true;
                }
                else if (number_of_spin>=5){theWheel.animation.duration=5;
                                           theWheel.startAnimation();

                    // Set to true so that power can't be changed and spin button re-enabled during
                    // the current animation. The user will have to reset before spinning again.
                    wheelSpinning = true;}
                    // Begin the spin animation by calling startAnimation on the wheel object.
                    
                }
            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Function for reset button.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function resetWheel()
            {
                theWheel.stopAnimation(false);  // Stop the animation, false as param so does not call callback function.
                theWheel.rotationAngle = 0;     // Re-set the wheel angle to 0 degrees.
                theWheel.draw();                // Call draw to render changes to the wheel.

              

                wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Called when the spin animation has finished by the callback feature of the wheel because I specified callback in the parameters
            // note the indicated segment is passed in as a parmeter as 99% of the time you will want to know this to inform the user of their prize.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function alertPrize(indicatedSegment)
            {
                // Do basic alert of the segment text. You would probably want to do something more interesting with this information.
                alert("You have won " + indicatedSegment.text);
            }
```

Comment: Please elaborate more. What is the name of the function which spins the wheel? Show your code so far, or an attempt to solve this problem. Otherwise I will not be able to give you accurate advice/solutions.

Comment: @AlphaHowl I included the code

Comment: Ok, great. So you want to repeat `startSpin` 5 times in certain circumstances, so that the wheel spins 5 times one after the other?

Comment: @AlphaHowl Yes I want to spin 5 times and in each time their will be a prize But i want it to appear to the user that it spin one time and gave him 5 prizes

Comment: Oh, so only one spin should be visible?

Comment: @AlphaHowl yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the animation after the first spin using the built-in `callbackFinished` and reset it after the remaining four spins (which should be instantaneous).
So set an integer variable `number_of_spins` to `0`, and increment by `1` after each spin.

Now, with each spin, check:

- `if(number_of_spins > 0)` then set the `animation.duration` to `0`
- `else if(number_of_spins >= 5)` reset the `animation.duration` to its default.

Here is how this would be done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>HTML5 Canvas Winning Wheel</title>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Winwheel.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
           
            <br />
            
            <br />
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="power_controls">
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <table class="power" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <th align="center">Power</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="78" align="center" id="pw3" onClick="powerSelected(3);">High</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" id="pw2" onClick="powerSelected(2);">Med</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" id="pw1" onClick="powerSelected(1);">Low</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br />
                            <img id="spin_button" src="spin_off.png" alt="Spin" onClick="startSpin(1);" />
                            <br /><br />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="resetWheel(); return false;">Play Again</a><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(reset)
                            <br>
                            <button onclick="startSpin(5)">5 spin</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="438" height="582" class="the_wheel" align="center" valign="center">
                        <canvas id="canvas" width="434" height="434">
                            <p style="{color: white}" align="center">Sorry, your browser doesn't support canvas. Please try another.</p>
                        </canvas>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            // Create new wheel object specifying the parameters at creation time.
            let theWheel = new Winwheel({
                'numSegments'  : 8,     // Specify number of segments.
                'outerRadius'  : 212,   // Set outer radius so wheel fits inside the background.
                'textFontSize' : 28,    // Set font size as desired.
                'segments'     :        // Define segments including colour and text.
                [
                   {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 1'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 2'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 3'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 4'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 5'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 6'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 7'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 8'}
                ],
                'animation' :           // Specify the animation to use.
                {
                    'type'     : 'spinToStop',
                    'duration' : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
                    'spins'    : 8,     // Number of complete spins.
                    'callbackFinished' : alertPrize
                }
            });

            // Vars used by the code in this page to do power controls.
            let wheelPower    = 0;
            let wheelSpinning = false;

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Function to handle the onClick on the power buttons.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function powerSelected(powerLevel)
            {
                // Ensure that power can't be changed while wheel is spinning.
                if (wheelSpinning == false) {
                    // Reset all to grey incase this is not the first time the user has selected the power.
                    document.getElementById('pw1').className = "";
                    document.getElementById('pw2').className = "";
                    document.getElementById('pw3').className = "";

                    // Now light up all cells below-and-including the one selected by changing the class.
                    if (powerLevel >= 1) {
                        document.getElementById('pw1').className = "pw1";
                    }

                    if (powerLevel >= 2) {
                        document.getElementById('pw2').className = "pw2";
                    }

                    if (powerLevel >= 3) {
                        document.getElementById('pw3').className = "pw3";
                    }

                    // Set wheelPower var used when spin button is clicked.
                    wheelPower = powerLevel;

                    // Light up the spin button by changing it's source image and adding a clickable class to it.
                    document.getElementById('spin_button').src = "spin_on.png";
                    document.getElementById('spin_button').className = "clickable";
                }
            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Click handler for spin button.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function startSpin(how_many_prizes)
            {
                how_many_prizes = Math.min(how_many_prizes, theWheel.numSegments);
                theWheel.how_many_prizes = how_many_prizes;
                // Ensure that spinning can't be clicked again while already running.
                if (wheelSpinning == false) {
                    // Based on the power level selected adjust the number of spins for the wheel, the more times is has
                    // to rotate with the duration of the animation the quicker the wheel spins.
                    if (wheelPower == 1) {
                        theWheel.animation.spins = 3;
                    } else if (wheelPower == 2) {
                        theWheel.animation.spins = 8;
                    } else if (wheelPower == 3) {
                        theWheel.animation.spins = 15;
                    }

                    // Disable the spin button so can't click again while wheel is spinning.
                    document.getElementById('spin_button').src       = "spin_off.png";
                    document.getElementById('spin_button').className = "";

                    // Begin the spin animation by calling startAnimation on the wheel object.
                    theWheel.startAnimation();

                    // Set to true so that power can't be changed and spin button re-enabled during
                    // the current animation. The user will have to reset before spinning again.
                    wheelSpinning = true;
                }
            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Function for reset button.
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            function resetWheel()
            {
                theWheel.stopAnimation(false);  // Stop the animation, false as param so does not call callback function.
                theWheel.rotationAngle = 0;     // Re-set the wheel angle to 0 degrees.
                theWheel.draw();                // Call draw to render changes to the wheel.

                document.getElementById('pw1').className = "";  // Remove all colours from the power level indicators.
                document.getElementById('pw2').className = "";
                document.getElementById('pw3').className = "";

                wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
            }


            let number_of_spins = 0;
            let prizes = new Set();
            const animation_time = 0;
            function alertPrize(indicatedSegment)
            {
                how_many_prizes = theWheel.how_many_prizes || 1;

                prizes.add(indicatedSegment.text);
                number_of_spins = prizes.size;

                if(number_of_spins > 0 && number_of_spins < how_many_prizes-1) {
                    theWheel.animation.spins = 1;
                    theWheel.animation.duration = animation_time;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        theWheel.startAnimation();
                        theWheel.spinning = true;
                    }, animation_time*1000);
                } 
                else if(number_of_spins == how_many_prizes-1) {
                    theWheel.animation.duration = animation_time*2.35;
                    theWheel.startAnimation();
                    theWheel.spinning = true;
                }
                else if(number_of_spins == how_many_prizes) {
                    theWheel.animation.duration = 5;
                    output_prizes();
                    reset_everything();
                    return;
                }

            }

            function output_prizes() {
                console.log("Here are your prizes: ");
                console.log(prizes);
            }
            function reset_everything() {
                number_of_spins = 0;
                prizes = new Set();
                theWheel.spinning = false;
                theWheel.animation.spins = 8;
                theWheel.animation.duration = 5;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: This script only gives each prize once, by using JS `Set()`s.

Comment: No problem, but I have not tested it, so i can't guarantee that it'll work...

Comment: It would be great if you test it. I tried to go by your answer but I think I did it the wrong way. Could you check my update

Comment: Ok, ill test it now.

Comment: I've got it. Check my answer. Also, I have created a variable `animation_time` which defaults to `0`. Try changing this to `.5` and see what happens :)

Comment: Oh, and you need to change the external link/script paths so they work on your computer.

Comment: it works thank you so much. But after the first click on spin button then the reset button to reset the wheel then if i clicked again on the spin button it gives me one prize only. like the 5 prize happens at the first click on spin button but then if i click again it start to give one prize.

Comment: Ah yeah, my mistake!!! I forgot to reset all the variables when the prizes are outputted. I have edited the answer, it should work now. Basically, I added a function `reset_everything`.

Comment: great it worked i also added some code to it. But Now i have two buttons one for 1 spin and the other is for 5 spin. Now the problem is in the `callbackFinished` I can add only one of the button. I created a function to check which button is clicked but didn't work

Comment: I can't see where you're trying to add the button in your question but i presume you could use window.event.target. Ps: if my answer worked for your original question please consider accepting it, I really appreciate it (as do future people viewing this post)

Comment: you can see in my first code. their is a spin button which originally can spin 1 time and give me one prize. I added the code you wrote to another button. Both button have `onClick="startSpin()"`   but they have different function for the prize. The first button have `alertPrize()` and the second have `alertPrize5()`  Now in the `callbackFinished` I can only specify one of the Prize function not both. How can I make it if user clicks on 1spin button the `callbackFinished` will call this `alertPrize()` and if user clicks on 5spin button the `callbackFinished` will call `alertPrize2()`

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer so now you pass the number of times you want it to spin into `startSpin`, for example `startSpin(3)` will give 3 prizes. See my answer for more.

Comment: one final issue is that sometime the 5 prizes option will give the same prize like this '["Prize 2", "Prize 2", "Prize 2", "Prize 2", "Prize 2"]'. Also, what if i want to disable a button. for example if user clicks on 1spin button the other should be disabled till the spin finishes and prize appear and vice versa for the 5 spin button. Sorry for my question. This the last one. And thank you so much for your help sir.

Comment: No problem. If you want to disable a `button`, use `button.style.pointerEvents = "none"; button.style.opacity = .3;`. As for eliminating duplicated prizes, see my updated answer. This is actually pretty easy to do, taking only 2 or 3 lines of code. The key is to stop incrementing `number_of_spins` by one with each spin, but to set it as the `size` (ie length) of the `Set` `prizes`. This way we stop spinning whenever we get as many prizes as we need. This is possible because `Set`s automatically delete equivalent elements. Sets are amazing!

Comment: You can convert/cast a set to an array like so: 

`let my_arr = Array.from(my_set);` 

And arrays to sets like so: 

`let my_set = new Set(my_arr);`

Comment: It didn't work with me when i click the 5 spin button nothing happens. I think this has to do with the fact that I'm using range for the random so that not any prize can come.

Comment: Did you click on "reset the wheel", because it works for me? Try to save the code I have written as is and test it again.

Comment: Have you changed the `src` and `href` etc attribures on all scripts because the paths are different on my computer.

Comment: yes I did. But like I said I'm using rage and perhaps that the issue. You check my Code for range here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/75qvo63s/)

Comment: That is happening because of an infinite loop. When you set the `stopAngle` to a certain angle, the wheel will stop spinning at that angle and chose the prize found at that angle, right?

Comment: So this means that the wheel will always stop at that angle - all 5 times it tries to spin. But because the animation is removed after the first time, you cannot see this. But the wheel will only ever chose one prize - the one found at the stopAngle...

Comment: But that prize has already been picked!!! The set `prizes` already contains that prize. So what does the wheel do? It spins again. But lands at the same prize again! So it spins again until it lands on a different prize... But it can never land on a different prize. So it never fills the Set with 5 prizes and continues trying to do so until infinity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233967/discussion-between-alphahowl-and-ghz-aln).